# Releasing all resources of Process

Tags: java, exec, runtime.exec

It seems like a basic issue, however I don't find a clear answer in Javadocs:

How to correctly release all resources allocated by `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` ?

Is calling `Process.waitFor()` enough or I have to manually close input, output and error stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If not explicitly written in the documentation You must explicitly close input, output and error stream.

`Process` is an abstract class and its concrete implementation may differ from operating system to operating system because it access resources of the operating system. So can't be sure that every implementation works the same, so closing explicitly is the best practice to apply in this context.